# Extjs 6.6 Filter Treepanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I'm trying to filter my treepanel based on user input, im following this fiddle to achieve this, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1oso, the extjs version in the fiddle is 5.1 and it works perfectly, but i'm trying on 6.6 verion,and the results are diferent, on 6.6 the tree only "updates" correctly when i click in a node, as seen in this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k7i (try writing "touch" on the search field, or write a random name that doesnt match with any node);

There's a workaround for this issue? or another way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just simplified the filter function and in extjs 6.6 works well.

[Here is an example on fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qq9)

See- if this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: The only problem with your solution is that it's only filtering leaf nodes, try search for "Touch" or "chores"

Comment: I just updated on fiddle, check out. Also, I added the display of all the parents. You can remove this - just delete `if (node.parentNode) {
                           var checkParent = checkParentNodeFn(node.parentNode);
                           if(checkParent){
                               return true;
                           }
                        }`

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, i just added node.parentNode.expand(), to expand the parent node in case it is collapsed